# Return only numbers from string using Google Analytics regex

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I have a URL, lets say:

google.com/?ZipCode=77007

How can I return only the number part of the URL? I'm using google analytics regex.

I tried something like this:
    \d{5}
and it matches the URL but doesn't isolate only the number.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If we wish to just get the zip code, these expressions might likely work:

```
ZipCode=([0-9]+)
ZipCode=([0-9]{5})
ZipCode=(\d+)
ZipCode=(\d{5})
```

which all have a missing capturing group `()`, that I'm guessing to be the issue here.

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/5ZWgEg/1/)

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

#### Demo

```js
const regex = /ZipCode=(\d+)/gm;
const str = `google.com/?ZipCode=77007`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The first expression works but it returns the entire URL and not just the numbers. Any idea how to do that?